# How to group by the elements in XSL

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an HTML of the following process.

```
<p class="Ahead">FIRST SECTION</p>
  <p class="Text">with a moisture content of 16.34</p>
  <p class="Ahead">SECOND SECTION</p>
    <p class="Bhead">Second First Section</p>
      <p class="Text">with a moisture content of 20.56</p>
      <p class="Chead">Second first first section</p>
        <p class="Text">with a moisture content of 48.15</p>
```

The Ahead, Bhead and Chead should be individual group. How it is possible to group it.

The output should be follow below.

```
<sec>
  <title>FIRST SECTION</title>
  <p class="Text">with a moisture content of 16.34</p>
</sec>
<sec>
  <title>SECOND SECTION</title>
  <sec
    <title>Second First Section</title>
    <p class="Text">with a moisture content of 20.56</p>
    <sec>
      <title>Second first first section</title>
      <p class="Text">with a moisture content of 48.15</p>
    </sec>
  </sec>
</sec>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<xsl:function name="f:group">
  <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:param name="population" as="element()*"/>
  <xsl:variable name="name" select="('Ahead', 'Bhead', 'Chead')[$level]"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$population"
    group-starting-with="p[@class=$name]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@class='Text'">
       <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:sequence select="f:group($level+1, current-group())"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose> 
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>
```

then:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="f:group(1, //p)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Not tested, just something for you to start with.

Comment: I can't tell you what you are doing wrong unless you tell me what you are doing.